# Conditional SQL SELECT - when return set is empty, execute another SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

I have webpage that has its "pages/articles" stored in a MySQL database. It also has a feature to show a different side menu for different pages.  All that (menus, menu's items) is stored in DB.

Here's my SQL for getting all menu items for current page:

```
SELECT * 
FROM menu_items 
   JOIN pages 
    ON menu_items.menu_id=pages.right_menu_id 
WHERE pages.link = "some_link"
```

and it works.

What I want is,  when this query returns an empty set, to execute another query and get its result instead.  Is it possible ?? If query mentioned above is empty, I would like to get result of this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM menu_items 
WHERE menu_id=2;
```

Is it possible, or should I just do it in PHP ?

Comment: You could find a way to do it (with union, for example, or a subquery) but I think you really ought to just do it in PHP.

Comment: yeah, after I've seen solution, I'll just do it in PHP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the EXIST function to test whether the current page has any links:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT menu_id FROM menu_items JOIN pages ON menu_items.menu_id = pages.right_menu_id WHERE pages.link = "some_link") THEN

    SELECT   * 
    FROM     menu_items 
             JOIN pages 
                 ON menu_items.menu_id=pages.right_menu_id 
    WHERE    pages.link = "some_link" 

ELSE

    SELECT   * 
    FROM     menu_items 
             JOIN pages 
                 ON menu_items.menu_id=pages.right_menu_id 
    WHERE    menu_id = 2

END IF
```

You could also try something like this:

```
DECLARE @LinkCount INT
SELECT @LinkCount = COUNT(*) FROM menu_items JOIN pages ON menu_items.menu_id = pages.right_menu_id WHERE pages.link = "some_link"

SELECT   * 
FROM     menu_items 
         JOIN pages 
             ON menu_items.menu_id=pages.right_menu_id 
WHERE    (@LinkCount > 0 AND pages.link = "some_link") OR (@LinkCount = 0 AND menu_id = 2)
```

There might be more elegant ways of doing this, but hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! It's good to know how it can be done, but I think PHP solution is more elegant and readable, so I'll implement it in PHP ;)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is not the most elegant way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    menu_items 
    JOIN pages ON menu_items.menu_id = pages.right_menu_id 
WHERE pages.link = "some_link"

UNION ALL

SELECT *, NULL, NULL, NULL 
FROM menu_items 
WHERE 
    menu_id = 2 AND 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM 
            menu_items 
            JOIN pages ON menu_items.menu_id = pages.right_menu_id 
        WHERE pages.link = "some_link"
    )
```

*Note: Number of NULLs should be the same as number of columns in table **pages**.*

Comment: Thanks :D But this just scares me :D